# Arduino/Swift - BLE communications POST & GET

Tags: ios, swift, arduino, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

How can I make a BLE communication with swift and arduino device?
Now with my code I'm able to send value to my BLE shield but I don't know how to send back a report to my swift application!

I use a HM-10 BLE module and Swift 2.0.

This is my arduino code:

```
  #include<SoftwareSerial.h>

  SoftwareSerial Try(1,0);

  void setup() {
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  Try.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Try.available()){
    switch(Try.read()){
      case('a') :{
        digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an easy code that when receive a char 'a' from my application, it switch on a green LED.
With that is all ok but i want to send back the report 'Green LED switched on!' to my Swift app.

So this is the Swift code to send the 'a' value to my BLE module.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


class Connection: UIViewController{

    var connee: CBCharacteristic!
    var per: CBPeripheral!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func SendingVal(sender: AnyObject) {

        let Sen = "a"
        let Value: NSData = Sen.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

        sendDataToCentral(per, characteristic: connee, data:  Value)

    }


    private func sendDataToCentral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, characteristic: CBCharacteristic, data: NSData) {
        peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)    }

}
```

So, how can I send back a report from BLE module to my swift app?

Comment: We guess that you did all the connection/reading services/characteristics. Do you see the value sent in your Arduino? Even if it's wrong?

Comment: I'm able to see all value in my arduino but... I don't know how to send back a report or a value

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794107/swift-ble-communications/39174444#39174444

Answer (score 0):

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
   print(characteristic)
}
```

get value from characteristic 
This delegate call when value is change.
peripheral discover this updated value.