# Write Data to Characteristic on Button Click - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy

I've managed to connect an ios app to my BLE hm-10 device and send it's characteristic a string. However I can't figure out how to send the string once a button is pressed using the @IBAction function.

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error:NSError?)
{
    print("Found \(service.characteristics!.count) characteristics!: \(service.characteristics)")
    _peripheral = peripheral
    _characteristics = service.characteristics
    let string = "off"

    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    for characteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!
    {

        if(characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "FFE1")
        {
            print("sending data")
            peripheral.writeValue(data!, forCharacteristic: characteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func onButtonTouch(sender: UIButton)
{
    let string = "on"

    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    _peripheral.writeValue(data!, forCharacteristic: _characteristics, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)

}
```

When I put this code into the @IBAction function shown at the bottom it does not work as "characteristic" is an unresolved identifier. Is there a way to link this to the peripheral function? I'm relatively new to coding in Swift so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to save the characteristic. In `onButtonTouch(sender:)` it's not declared!

Comment: why can't you make `peripheral` and `characteristic` as global variables?

Comment: @Larme Thanks for quick answer. Really sorry to sound like such a newbie but would you be able to explain to me how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: @DashAndRest How would I go about making them global variables? Thanks.

Comment: Make them properties, not globals

Comment: Here is another similar question that can probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794107/swift-ble-communications/39174444#39174444

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class viewController: UIViewController {

    var _peripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var _characteristics: [CBCharacteristic]?

    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error:NSError?)
    {
    print("Found \(service.characteristics!.count) characteristics!: \(service.characteristics)")
    _peripheral = peripheral
    _characteristics = service.characteristics
    let string = "off"

    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


       for characteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!
        {

            if(characteristic.UUID.UUIDString == "FFE1")
            {
                print("sending data")
                peripheral.writeValue(data!, forCharacteristic: characteristic,type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)
            }
        }

    }

    @IBAction func onButtonTouch(sender: UIButton)
    {
    let string = "on"

    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let characteristic = //get right on out of _characteristics! array
    _peripheral!.writeValue(data!, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithoutResponse)

    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem with the characteristic identifier however i'm now getting errors regarding the viewController saying "Class viewController has no initializers" and the CharacteristicsDataType/Class? section saying "consecutive declarations on a line must be seperated". Sorry to be a pain.

Comment: @DanB what error? `view controller` I mentioned just for an example. show your whole class that contains your code.

Comment: @DanB you have to replace `CharacteristicsDataType/Class` with the actual data type of `[CBCharacteristic]`. check updated answer

Comment: Getting an error at 'forCharacteristic: _characteristics!' of "Cannot convert value of type '[CBCharacteristic]" to expected argument type 'CBCharacteristic'". Really appreciate your help.

Comment: coz `_characteristics` is an array, you need to get right one characteristic from that array

Comment: Actually I can't say that, but you need to apply business logic to get right characteristic or allocate new one!