# How to write data from iOS Swift 3 app to BLE (HM-10)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to send data from the iPhone to HM-10

I have establish a connection with the bluetooth device, however I don't know how to send the data, is this a peripheral delegate function?

When a button is pressed a fixed integer(1,2,3,4...) is to be sent to the BLE device once.
Furthermore, I have slider, and I would like the value of the slider to be sent across to

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for this method:

```
CBPeripheral.func writeValue(_ data: Data, for characteristic: CBCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType)
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518747-writevalue

Comment: Hi Lars, I saw the link you referenced, however when i try to do the function writeValue in the button IBAction func bit there is no option for writeValue.
e.g. I will do mainPeripheral. and there is not the choice to choose 'writeValue'

Comment: Do you already have a `CBPeripheral` instance from a peripheral discovery?

Comment: No, I have two view controllers. On one viewcontroller I have a tableview which I use to connect to the bluetooth. On the second viewcontroller I have the buttons that I want to press to send the information to the bluetooth. On the second view controller I am currently using CBPeripheralDelegate only. Is this correct?

Comment: Lars, I have managed to get the writeValue to appear. However what information do I put into the Data/CBCharacteristic? i am not sure there. This example has some but not the full answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794107/swift-ble-communications)

Comment: Do you know how many bytes the characteristic accepts as its input?

Comment: You can install the free app "nRF connect" on your phone to try out writing to the characteristic. It also allows to read values from characteristics.

Comment: Hi Lars, sorry for the delay - I currently have:
    var writeType: CBCharacteristicWriteType = .withoutResponse
    var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
        let value = [UInt8(1)]
        let data = NSData(bytes: value, length: value.count)
        mainPeripheral?.writeValue(data as Data, for: writeCharacteristic!, type: writeType)
        print("Button pressed")

xcode has no error but the data isn't receiving on the arduino. i will try the nRF app to see what happens there too

Answer (score 0):

Before you will write your data to device using CBPerpheral.writeValue function you have to discover that characteristics, services and keep a strong reference to them.

Everything is described in that tutorial from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1

It's in Obj-C but it's easy to translate that into swift

Comment: thanks for the answer, however I am not so good at swift, thus changing to swift from Obj-C is another layer on complications i don't need :/